# Cannot find Excel in Javascript Chart API

Tags: excel, office-js, office-app

I was trying to use this Microsoft tutorial [Excel Chart Add-in - Javascript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-charts)

In the first example, it has the code

```
Excel.run(function (context) {
    var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:B13");
    var chart = sheet.charts.add("Line", dataRange, "auto");

    chart.title.text = "Sales Data";
    chart.legend.position = "right"
    chart.legend.format.fill.setSolidColor("white");
    chart.dataLabels.format.font.size = 15;
    chart.dataLabels.format.font.color = "black";

    return context.sync();
}).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
```

If I run the code example I receive 2 errors. One that it cannot find excel from

```
Excel.run
```

And the errorhandler function is not defined, which appears to be correct.

Are these typos in new Microsoft documents? If not what have I got to change?

Version: excel 365 online build 16.0.13615.35052

Comment: Can you provide more details about what Excel Version you are using? (i.e. send the details in File->Account->About excel

Comment: @JuanBalmori Its excel 365 online build 16.0.13615.35052

Comment: I cant find a release with such build number, is this the Excel for Windows or Universal? if you can provide a screenshot will be great. i added an answer after trying the code, in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

2 things that you need to make sure you have in order to run this code succesfully.

1. Please add the errorHandlerFunction this could be be as easy as this:

```js
function errorHandlerFunction(e ){
  console.log("exception" + e ); 
}
```

2. Make sure you have a worksheet named "Sample". Make sure its exactly that name without trailing blank spaces.